# keep getting mysql syntax error in my java code?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, syntax-error

I am working on an email database program and I continue to get a syntax error when I try to store emails into the database and I am not exactly sure why it is happening. I stored user objects the exact same way and although it did store user objects into the database, it ended up updating some values in my database rather than inserting a new values when I exited out of the program and tested the program again. Could the syntax error be coming from the fact that some of my columns store Blobs?

MYSQL:

```
 'CREATE TABLE `item` (\n  `Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\',\n  `To`               varchar(300) NOT NULL COMMENT \'To\',\n  `From` varchar(300) NOT NULL,\n  `Subject` varchar(45) NOT NULL COMMENT \'subject\',\n  `topic` varchar(45) NOT NULL COMMENT \'category\',\n  `Email_Content` blob NOT NULL COMMENT \'Email Content may change\',\n  `Comments` blob,\n  `Attachments` blob,\n  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)\n) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT    CHARSET=utf8'
```

Database class:

```
public void storeItem() throws SQLException{
    String checkSql = "select count(*) as count from item where Id=?";
    PreparedStatement checkStatement = con.prepareStatement(checkSql);

    String storeSql = "insert into item(Id, To, From, Subject, topic, Email_Content, Comments, Attachments) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement insertStatement = con.prepareStatement(storeSql);

    String updateSql = "insert into set To=? From=?, Subject=?, topic=?, Email_Address=?, Comments=?, Attachments=? where Id=?";
    PreparedStatement updateStatement = con.prepareStatement(updateSql);

    for(Item items: Items){
        int ItemId = items.getId();
        String To = items.getTo();
        String From = items.getFrom();
        String Subject = items.getSubject();
        String Topic = items.getTopic();
        String Email = items.getMessageContent();
        String Comments = items.getComments();
        String attachments = items.getAttachments();

        checkStatement.setInt(1, ItemId);
        ResultSet checkResult = checkStatement.executeQuery();
        checkResult.next();
        int count = checkResult.getInt(1);

        if (count == 0) {
            System.out.println("Inserting person with ID " + ItemId);
            int col = 1;
            insertStatement.setInt(col++, ItemId);
            insertStatement.setString(col++, To);
            insertStatement.setString(col++, From);
            insertStatement.setString(col++, Subject);
            insertStatement.setString(col++, Topic);
            insertStatement.setString(col++, Email);
            insertStatement.setString(col++, Comments);
            insertStatement.setString(col++, attachments);
            insertStatement.executeUpdate();

        } else {
            System.out.println("Updating person with ID " + ItemId);
            int col = 1;
            updateStatement.setString(col++, To);
            updateStatement.setString(col++, From);
            updateStatement.setString(col++, Subject);
            updateStatement.setString(col++, Topic);
            updateStatement.setString(col++, Email);
            updateStatement.setString(col++, Comments);
            updateStatement.setString(col++, attachments);
            updateStatement.setInt(col++, ItemId);

            updateStatement.executeUpdate();
        }

         System.out.println("Count for person with ID " + ItemId + " is " + count);
    }
    updateStatement.close();
    insertStatement.close();
    checkStatement.close();


}
```

Controller class

```
    public void storeItem() throws SQLException{
    dc.storeItem();
}
```

MainFrame class

```
public void completeEventOccurred() {
            if (LoadEmailPanel.getComplete() == true) {
                String To = LoadEmailPanel.getText(1);
                String From = LoadEmailPanel.getText(2);
                String Subject = LoadEmailPanel.getText(3);
                String Topic = LoadEmailPanel.getText(4);
                String Email = LoadEmailPanel.getText(5);
                String Notes = LoadEmailPanel.getText(6);
                String Attach = LoadEmailPanel.getText(7);

                EmailEvent ev = new EmailEvent(this, To, From, Subject,
                        Topic, Email, Notes, Attach);
                controller.addEmail(ev);
                connect();
                try {
                    controller.storeItem();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



                cards.show(MainFrame.this.getContentPane(), "Home");
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: This is what the stack trace is giving me.

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server for the right syntax to use near 'To, From, Subject,topic, Email_Content, Comments, Attachments)  values (1, 'abhila' at line 1

Comment: `To` is a [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html)

Comment: @Kerpal: There are reserved words in MySQL. [Check them out here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). You need to escape them with backticks when using as column or table names

Comment: updating statement is incorrect, should be  `update item set`, not `insert into set`

Comment: I changed the reserved word 'To' to 'Sender' and 'From' to 'Reciever' in MySQL and I corrected the mistake that user1516873 mentioned and now my program works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm having another problem with my update and insert statement. Every time I close and reopen the application, my update statement keeps overriding the item objects that are in my database every time I try to add a new item. How can I make it so that my database stores new item objects as values in my Item table under the values that are already there.

Answer (score -1):

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,query);
```

This will help you find syntax error in your query
Use combination of single and double quotes in your query

insertQuery ="Insert Into TableName(Name, EnrollmentNo ,Country)values("+" ' "+Mack" ' , " + 12103596 " , ' " + India + " ')";

Comment: proposed solution vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: I found my syntax error for my program. It was just the reserved words and my update statement error. Thanks for your input.